# How to not use null object?

Tags: react-native

*I have object like this :*

```
let collection = {
  first: '',
  second: '',
  third: '',
  Fourth: '',
};
```

*My question is that, I use this in flatlist and some attributes come empty so I dont want to use them because when I put these to a box, they take up space.
How can I handle this ?*

**This is my code:**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView>
    <FlatList 
      data={this.state.AllMetarials}
      extraData={this.state}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      numColumns={1}
      renderItem={ ({ item }) => {
        return ( 
          <View style={{ width: '50%', marginLeft: '2%', marginTop: '2%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#00cec9', opacity: 0.7 }} >
            <Text>{item.first}</Text>
            <Text>{item.second}</Text> 
            <Text>{item.third}</Text>
            <Text>{item.Fourth}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

**EDİTED:**

*I did like this and it works*

```
 <View style={{ width: '50%', height: 80, marginLeft: '2%', marginTop: '2%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#00cec9', opacity: 0.7 }} >
                                {item.first!== '' ? <Text> { item.first} </Text> : undefined}
                                {item.second!== '' ? <Text> { item.second} </Text> : undefined}
                                {item.third!== '' ? <Text> { item.third} </Text> : undefined}
                                {item.Fourth!== '' ? <Text> { item.Fourth} </Text> : undefined}
                            </View>
```

Comment: where does your collection object come into this? Can you explain further as I am struggling to understand

Comment: Can you explain why you have a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` when it is already scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

Your object can look like:

```
const myObject = {
  first: '',
  second: '',
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView>
    <FlatList 
      data={this.state.AllMetarials}
      extraData={this.state}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      numColumns={1}
      renderItem={ ({ item }) => {
        return ( 
          <View style={{ width: '50%', marginLeft: '2%', marginTop: '2%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#00cec9', opacity: 0.7 }} >
            {item.first && <Text>{item.first}</Text>}
            {item.second && <Text>{item.second}</Text>} 
            {item.third && <Text>{item.third}</Text>}
            {item.Fourth && <Text>{item.Fourth}</Text>}
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

In javascript `&&` will make sure that the next statement is executed only when the evaluated value is not null, not empty, not zero or not undefined.

Comment: this gives me error like  'text string must be rendered within a Text component'